# ExpressJS PATCH request redirection with GET method

Tags: javascript, express, redirect

I have a problem when I want to refresh the page when admin changes type of a user. This code is responsible for that:

```
router.patch('/update/admin', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, { userType: 'admin' });
    if (user) res.status(301).redirect('/users');
    else res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
  } catch (error) {
    logger(error);
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

Changing admin to user is similar.

After commiting the change, I get such error on console:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)
```

*That's the endpoint for page to manage users*

Isn't redirect() creating a GET request always? Can I somehow force it to do so? My other routes work properly with redirections.

Comment: I think you should redirect with 303 status to redirect with the GET request type

Comment: doesn't change anything :(